# i am unable to import anything from activity_main.xml to MainActivity.kt by its id such as textview or button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I saw I lot of videos says that the Kotlin can recognize the buttons (views) automatically in MainActivity.kt I try this but it doesn't work for me in android studio 4.1 when I'm using the usual code with :

```
var button_name = findViewById(R.id.buttonName)
```

it works fine but when I'm using the code directly like this :

```
buttonName.setonclicklistiner{}
```

the IDE doesn't recognize the button

PS : this the imports in the mainactivity

```
import android.os.Bundle

import android.view.View

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

What can i do for access my button or textView automatically in MainActivity.kt

Comment: put your complete code for buttonName.setonclicklistiner{}

Comment: thats the problem when i type buttonName its does't recognize autometically, if i type buttonName manually than font colour is red and shows error

Answer (score 10):

In build.gradle(module) make sure plugins contains following 3 plugins -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me. I lacked the '-extensions' one.

Answer (score 4):

Open `build_gradle(:app)` and make sure you have these two lines in `dependencies` block

```
dependencies {

    apply plugin : "kotlin-android"

    apply plugin : "kotlin-android-extensions"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have these 2 lines at the top of your gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 1):

At first go to build.gradle.kts(module : app), in that file

check for buildFeatures in android tag or property

```
 android{
         // let the other value as it is
         buidFeatures{
                compose = true
         }
   }
```

there add this line
`viewBinding = true`

so now your code looks like this

```
 android{
          buildfeatures{
                compose = true
                viewBinding = true
           }
    }
```

now sync the gradle file by clicking sync now button
this will create a binding file for every xml file you have (if your xml file is activity_main then the generated binding file will be ActivityMainBinding)
and now we have to import that binding file into our kotlin code

to do that go to your main_activity.kt file and add this line in imports

```
import com.example.yourappname.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

change the yourappname to whatever your app name is and ActivityMainBinding to your geanerated binding file

now we have to create an instance of this binding, before that we will intialize a variable of ActivityMainBinding type

do this initialisation inside MainActivity class outside and before any function declarations, like this

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(){

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

now let us instantiate the instance of our binding class do this in onCreate function

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
```

check out for errors as your binding file name may be different

so your onCreate function should look like above now you can use binding instance to refer the UI elements in your xml file from which you created this binding instance

to do that let us say you have button element in your UI and it's Id attribute is set to 'button' and you want to change the text attribute you can do that in onCreate ( because you instantiated the binding instance or you can instantiate it anywhere and use it anywhere ) function like this

```
binding.button.text = "your wish whatever you want"
```

for more info you can visit here https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation

Answer (score 0):

If your xml name is "activity_main.xml" then import like below:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Comment: when i try to import this, kotlinx font colour got red and shows error

Answer (score 0):

You must import the xml file into your kotlin folder by insert

```
import com.example.yourappsname.databinding.ActivityMainPageBinding
```

Change "ActivityMainPageBinding" to your XML file name. Incase your XML file name is "name_folder", your import should be

```
import com.example.yourappsname.databinding.NameFolderBinding
```

Also do not forget to change "yourappsname" to your real application name.

Answer (score 0):

weird solution but it works
example you have a button called btnfirst

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.btnfirst as btnfirst1

```
btnfirst1.setOnClickListener {
        if (rs.moveToFirst()) {
            edid.setText(rs.getInt(0))
            edname.setText(rs.getText(1))
            edmarks.setText(rs.getText(2))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions provided above worked for me .
Only the weird solution that i provided removed errors.

weird solution but it works example you have a button called btnfirst

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.btnfirst as btnfirst1

btnfirst1.setOnClickListener {
    if (rs.moveToFirst()) {
        edid.setText(rs.getString(0))
        edname.setText(rs.getString(1))
        edmarks.setText(rs.getString(2))
    }
}
```